# cat and xargs with scp : No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, scp, xargs

I'm trying to copy files from a remote machine to my local machine:

`resource.txt`

```
/path/dir/file1.txt
/path/dir/file2.txt
/path/dir/file3.txt
```

`cat resource.txt | xargs -I F scp <user@ip>:F /localpath/dir/`

I'm getting something like this `: No such file or directoryir/file1.txt`

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line terminators in your `resource.txt` file are probably wrong. Please, run the following command:

```
strings resource.txt >new_resource.txt
```

and use the `new_resource.txt` file created.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks. `cat -v ` showed `^M` in resource.txt

Comment: Use `cat -e new_resource.txt`; you will see `$` at the end of lines (which indicate the correct line terminator for Linux). Use `cat -e resource.txt`; you will probably see `^M` in place of line terminators and everything will be displayed in a single line (this will indicate that _Carriage Returns_ have been used instead of the correct _Line Feeds_).